# Cannot connect c# driver with the instance of Cassandra on amazon ec2

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I'm trying to configure Cassandra on aws EC2, but I neither can do cqlsh "my public server ip" nor connect it from C# driver.
Cqlsh returns can't connect to server, and c# driver returns request timeout when connecting to a new session of my keyspace.

here's

```
> ps -ef | grep CassandraDaemon ; netstat -lntp | grep <pid>

from server: 
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xx:7000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6088/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50013         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6088/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6088/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9160            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6088/java       
tcp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            :::*                    LISTEN      6088/java
```

p.s: xx.xx.xx.xx is my private server ip, not public.

EDIT: here's the security group screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How is rpc_address and broadcast_rpc_address configured in cassandra.yaml?   If you are trying to connect from a client that is running outside EC2 rpc_address either needs to be the public ip or broadcast_rpc_address needs to be.

Comment: i have set rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 and broadcast_rpc_address to my private server ip, should i change it to my public server ip which i am using to connect ssh ??

Comment: ah yes, that should fix it (you'll need to restart cassandra after making that change).  If it still doesn't work, it may be a security group problem as E.J. suggests.

Comment: Just to clarify, broadcast_rpc_address should be the public ip while rpc_address can remain 0.0.0.0 or be your private ip.

Comment: I changed broadcast_rpc_address to the public ip, and restarted, tried cqlsh "my public ip" it returned 'Unable to connect to any servers'

Comment: One thing I noticed that is slightly peculiar is that port 9042 (thats the port cql is on) is listening on an ipv6 address.  Just curious, would you mind settings rpc_address to your private ipv4 address instead and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I changed my rpc_address to private ip, restarted server, tried cqlsh "my public ip", 'Unable to connect to any servers'.. one more thing, my listen_address is also private ip

Comment: I have uploaded screenshot for groups, i tried deleting the default one before adding All ports open source 0.0.0.0/0 rule, but it denied, instead i added this one, the other rule is for ssh, comment on it pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89864/discussion-between-arsalan-saleem-and-andy-tolbert).

Comment: anyone ?? still not able to figure out..

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response, had to leave after my last comment.  Did you ever figure it out?  It might be worth checking to see if you can use cqlsh from the same server running cassandra, just to make sure you can at least talk to C* locally.

Comment: yup, cqlsh was working too.. but problem resolved, i added rules to ssh group with specific ports, and baam welcome to cassandra :), thanks for your support.